# When waking up from screensaver, the screen is initially black

Tags: windows-7, screensaver

Using Windows 7 SP1 64-bit, without Aero. I'm *not* connecting through remote control. This problem does *not* occur when the machine comes out of standby/hibernate.

My screensaver is set to "blank". When I move the mouse to get out of the screensaver the screen will be black. When I start moving the cursor it's like I'm drawing/refreshing segments of the screen. If I tab to a window that is maximized, the whole screen will be refreshed at once.

This problem appeared after I've replaced my old monitor with a minutely newer monitor: a LG Flatron L1930P.

I'm assuming its a monitor issue, however I'm not sure how to fix it. Help?

Comment: Try a different, known-good monitor (and cable) and see if it behaves the same way.

Comment: I'd think graphics driver issue, or struggling for graphics memory. If you grab a window & drag it round the screen does the area behind where you drag it refresh? [assuming live window dragging, not border] Any change with Aero on? I'm pretty sure that disabling Aero on Win7 affects hardware skinning & is not necessarily wise to do [unless it's a very low-end GPU]

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: with a different monitor (same cable) it works fine. Tetsujin: yes, it does. My GPU is integrated into the CPU, so I assume it's pretty low-end.